# Как получить определенное значение из БД по id?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть код:

```
// Устанавливаем соединение(соединение работает! ошибок в нем нет.)
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$urlPhotо = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ImgSrc FROM products WHERE Id='$id'");
```

Но почему-то я получаю пустоту. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Мне больше интересно, там, где вы смотрели этот код, ничего больше не написано про извлечение данных?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно извлечь ответ запроса (офф. дока):

```
/* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```